# Ender 3 v2 printing problem

Tags: creality-ender-3, underextrusion

Last week, my printer worked really well, but after a print it started having some printing problems. The printer stops extruding mid-print or under extrudes.

After this happened, I

- leveled the bed again
- increased hotend temperature from 200 to 215 °C (PLA)
- changed slicer (I was using Ultimaker Cura), now I'm using Creality slicer
- changed the transmission ratio 93 to 106 according to this video

After making adjustments according to the video, the printer still stops extruding mid-print or under extrudes. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi Ahmet! Did you run into the underextrusion problems on multiple print files or just the one? Is it stopping in the same point in the print or a different one each time?

Comment: We've cleared up the question as the original question was not very clear, please feel free to change it or add additional information. Your problem sounds like heat creep, a cooling issue or a too high hotend temperature in combination with incorrect retraction settings may cause this. Please add some information on retraction and hotend cooling. Maybe adding an image of the failed prints provide extra information for people to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

One common reason for extrusion to stop in the middle of a print is heat creep.  See [What are ways to avoid heat creep?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15629/what-are-ways-to-avoid-heat-creep)