# Filament jam on the tube entrance

Tags: filament-jam

I have a problem in regards to filament jam, however I don't think that my case is any related to the extruder nozzle.
After 30 to 40 minutes printing my filament bends and get stuck on the tube entrance.
To print a nut wheel which comes as a demo file, I had to repeat the operation 4 times, and I had to stop printing when it got stuck, and continue with the printing, which led to a small imperfection.
What's the problem? The filament? The printer? Myself?
I have a Voxelab Aquila (completely new) and the filament u just a generic PLA from Amazon.

[image: Filament jam]
[image: Filament jam from another angle]

Answer (score 2):

Something is stopping the filament from going down the tube 30 to 40 min. after you start printing.  You are correct that this doesn't sound like a clogged nozzle.  It could be deformed filament, but the closeness of the timing after the start sounds like heat creep.  Other possibilities are also listed at the linked stackexchange article.

Note: with heat creep the filament will not jam in the tube.  It will jam just above the nozzle on a Bowden tube extruder; thus the filament stops going down the tube.  The tube entrance is probably the largest location the tube can kink, although not very large.

[What are ways to avoid heat creep?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15629/what-are-ways-to-avoid-heat-creep)

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the Bowden tube coupler from the extruder and clip that mangled end. If the tube isn't straight, it will cause friction and other problems.

Second, your filament should not have gear marks biting into it but the white tube shouldn't be visible between the gears.

Answer (score 0):

You need a better filament quality I have the same printer and I had switched to Overture. Know use PLA Plus  or (PLA+)due to not sticking to the bed well enough and your issue. And this issue may be the way the entire module moves up and down the threads may need better positioning like tighten loosen or even level it out check for a bend.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Could you clarify the answer, as it is now, it is pretty hard to read. I think that there is some useful information, but there are also parts that can be left out (Overture, PLA+ and not sticking to the bed). When it is more clear, you might receive upvotes. Thanks.