# PETG configuration

Tags: print-quality, petg

Recently, I have started to use PETG as my new material, before that I had been using ABS. But I stopped using ABS because of the cracking. I have been printing a lot of calibration cubes and I thought I was ready to print a bigger piece. This is the result, it has small holes and empty lines in the walls. On the top, I don't know what happened.

I have a Tronxy cube x5 which I use together with Cura. I print in PETG at 230 °C.The print bed is set to 65 °C. I use a print cooling fan at 30 %. The layer height I set to 0.2 mm, the line width  from the 0.3 mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 20 mm/s for walls and 35 mm/s for infill. My retraction is  4 mm/off at 20 mm/s.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Hello Cartox. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

Comment: This is underextrusion, the question is what is causing this. In order to answer the question we need more information as suggested by the previous comment. Could be the speed is too high.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have moisture in the filament.  Also, Your hotend temperature may be too low.  See Printing PETG in [Material to use inside ultrasonic cleaner](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19846/material-to-use-inside-ultrasonic-cleaner/19851#19851)